# Backbone is null

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using backbone and require js for a simple app I am trying to make. However, every time I try to run the app in the browser I get a "Backbone is null" error. I pin pointed it to the line where it try's to extend the Backbone model, but I have no idea why Backbone comes in as null? Anyone have any suggestions? I have been reading up on and messing around with the require.config but it still doesn't work.

```
//main.js (this is my data-main)

require.config({
     baseUrl: 'scripts/lib',
     paths: {
         'model': '../app/models'
     },
     waitSeconds: 30,
     shim: {
         'backbone': {
             deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
             exports: 'Backbone'
         },
         'underscore': {
             exports: '_'
         }
     }
 });
 require([
     'jquery',
     'underscore',
     'backbone',
     'model/comic'
 ], function (
     $,
     _,
     Backbone,
     Comic
 ) {
     console.log("Files loaded successfully");
 });

 //comic.js (this is my model)

 require(["backbone"], function (Backbone) {
     return Backbone.Model.extend({
         initialize: function (options) {
             this.comicName = options.comicName || "";
             this.author = options.author || "";
             this.issueNumber = options.issueNumber || "";
             console.log(this.comicName);
         }
     });
 });
```

> ```
> Directory Hierarchy
> -------------------
>     main.html
>     assets
>       scripts
>         app
>           models
>             comic.js
>         lib
>           backbone.js
>           underscore.js
>           require.js
>           jquery.js
>       styles
>         bootstrap.min.css
> ```

Comment: Could you please try require instead of define.

Comment: Alright, so I tried require instead of define and it executed the function once the dependencies were loaded. So I see "Files loaded successfully," however, it still throws the Backbone is undefined error. Any idea as to why? Thanks for the help by the way. Also why did require work and not define?

Answer (score 2):

In your paths object you need to tell requirejs where to find the backbone .js file with the alias of 'backbone'. You will have to do the same with underscore and jquery

```
paths:{
    'model' : '../app/models',
    'backbone' : 'path/to/backbone-min', //note you don't put the .js extension here
    'underscore' : 'path/to/underscore-min',
    'jquery' : 'path/to/jquery-min'

},
```

Comment: Sorry I should have said something about the directory hierarchy. Backbone, jQuery, and underscore are located in the scripts/lib folder, which was specified by the baseUrl property. So, correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that take care of those paths?

Comment: That should work, as long as it is named as follows `lib/backbone.js`